# Add single quote at start and end of a word followed by comma visual studio code

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I have items picked up from an excel column sheet and copied to visual studio code that looks something like below all items in new line

`item1 item2 item3 item4 . . . more 100 items lets say`

I am expecting a formatted string in visual studio code like below in a single line
`'item1','item2','item3','item4', .... 100 items`

How can I achieve that in visual studio ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your using mac for to

1. Select all elements by doing CMD + A
2. Goto Selections -> Add cursors to line ends

You will see something like this

[cursor addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ElsS.png)

3. Add ',

It will look something like below

[addition of desired literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aZKs.png)

4. Press CMD + Shift + left-arrow

It will look something like below

[Bringing cursor to start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CT8S.png)

6. Then type ' or your preferred literal

[starting cursor literal addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc5iy.png)

7. For bringing them to single line press delete by bringing cursor to start again.

[Single line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZlDX.png)